# How to access MethodChannel of Flutter engine created with FlutterActivity.withNewEngine()?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to create a Android app which launches flutter inside it. I have learnt that we can pass data to flutter via MethodChannels like this:

```
MethodChannel(
                FlutterEngineCache.getInstance().get(NEARBY_PLACES_ENGINE_KEY)?.dartExecutor?.binaryMessenger,
                "APP_CHANNEL"
        ).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            if (call.method == "getGreetings") {
                val coordinates = "Hello"
                result.success(coordinates)
            }
        }

startActivity(FlutterActivity
                .withCachedEngine(NEARBY_PLACES_ENGINE_KEY)
                .build(this))
```

This is possible when I have access to FlutterEngine instance (In this case with help of `FlutterEngineCache`). But how do we get the BinaryMessenger of a engine created with `FlutterActivity.withNewEngine()` ? Please help. TIA!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so I found the way to do it.

Created a custom `FlutterActivity` class and added that in the manifest instead of the one from `io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity`. The custom FlutterActivity extends from `FlutterActivity`, and overrides some methods to be able to access the newEngine.

```
class CustomFlutterActivity : FlutterActivity() {

    companion object {
        var methodChannelInvoker: (MethodCall, Result) -> Unit = { _, _ -> }

        fun withCachedEngine(cachedEngineId: String): CachedEngineIntentBuilder {
            return CachedEngineIntentBuilder(CompassFlutterActivity::class.java, cachedEngineId)
        }

        fun withNewEngine(): NewEngineIntentBuilder {
            return NewEngineIntentBuilder(CompassFlutterActivity::class.java)
        }
    }

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, "APP_CHANNEL")
                .setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
                    methodChannelInvoker(call, result)
                }
    }
}
```

and at the launch site,

```
CustomFlutterActivity.methodChannelInvoker = { call, result ->
            if (call.method == "getGreetings") {
                val greetings = "Hello there!"
                result.success(coordinates)
            }
        }
        startActivity(CustomFlutterActivity
                .withNewEngine()
                .initialRoute("/custom_route")
                .build(this))
```

This way, when the new engine launches, you get callback at `configureFlutterEngine` with new engine as parameter, we can simply access `dartExecutor` at that point.

Oh yes, and don't forget to add the `CustomFlutterActivity` in the manifest instead of `FlutterActivity`.